# Switching views without dismissing View

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, storyboard, view

I am developing a small music application in which first view comprises of all the List of songs in Tableview and when user taps on any one row (song) it takes them to Second view & Plays the song their(comprising of play/Pause Buttons). Now I go back in First View from Second View using back button to select another song. And their is one button in First View for just switching views(i.e it takes to current playing song)but it plays that same song from start but not from its currentplaying . Its similar to now Playing button in Stock Music app in iOS.
Im using storyboards & Segues

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
temp = indexPath.row;
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Player" sender:self];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Player"])
  {

    MPMediaItem *item = [itemCollections objectAtIndex:temp];
    NSString *trackInfo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@- %@",[item   valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle],[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist]];
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    NSURL *tempURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    playerController = [segue destinationViewController];
    playerController.fileUrl1 = tempURL;
    playerController.globalVar = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp];
    playerController.labelTitleString = trackInfo;
    playerController.img = [artwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go about this in many ways -- I would suggest implementing a [singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) to handle the media playback. Rather than constantly retaining that view, this singleton manager (part of your model) should provide any controllers with the needed information about the current song, album, author, etc.

Ex. In your TableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setSong:[[PlaybackManager sharedInstance] currentSong]];
    if (self.song) {
        //Add navigation item
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , I am not able to understand that. Actually My App Delegate is handling all the music playback.

Comment: I _very highly_ suggest you don't use your AppDelegate for that. Your AppDelegate is not some fat catchall singleton; put that logic where it belongs.

Comment: Likewise i have this code in app delegate.h

@property(strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger globalVar;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *itemm; i have only declared one instance in App delegate so that its easy for me to share playback information in both the views

Comment: My answer stands -- move that out of your AppDelegate and into a singleton, import that singleton class in your UITableViewController, and use the shared instance to determine if/what current song is playing.

Comment: Ok. I will Implement that and will report here if i faced any problems. Thank you so much..!..for such useful suggestions